build.gradle.kts:10:49: Cannot access 'serviceOf': it is internal in 'org.gradle.configurationcache.extensions'
e: /node_modules/@react-native/gradle-plugin/build.gradle.kts:10:49: Cannot access 'serviceOf': it is internal in 'org.gradle.configurationcache.extensions'
e: /node_modules/@react-native/gradle-plugin/build.gradle.kts:45:11: Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch:
internal inline fun  TaskInternal.serviceOf(): TypeVariable(T) defined in org.gradle.configurationcache.extensions
Build file '/node_modules/@react-native/gradle-plugin/build.gradle.kts' line: 10
Script compilation errors:

Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

Exception is:
ScriptCompilationException(errors=[ScriptCompilationError(message=Cannot access 'serviceOf': it is internal in 'org.gradle.configurationcache.extensions', location=/private/var/folders/mt/lt1qt3y93g9gfsyl2vg6qkq00000gn/T/gradle-kotlin-dsl-10130061735515911946.tmp/build.gradle.kts (10:49)), ScriptCompilationError(message=Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch:
internal inline fun  TaskInternal.serviceOf(): TypeVariable(T) defined in org.gradle.configurationcache.extensions, location=/private/var/folders/mt/lt1qt3y93g9gfsyl2vg6qkq00000gn/T/gradle-kotlin-dsl-10130061735515911946.tmp/build.gradle.kts (45:11))])


react-native 0.72.5
gradle 8.0.1
node V20
jdk 11

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

To update React Native and resolve Gradle issues:
Clean the project:
Delete the node_modules folder and package-lock.json file.
Reinstall dependencies:
Run
npm install 

to reinstall all necessary packages.
Use Gradle:
Now you should be able to use Gradle without any issues.
